# Iterated function system using java

Tags: java

I need to create a framework that would produce a range of [Interated function systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system), but I'm unsure of where to begin. I've produced a recursive function before and worked with GUI in java for only a few months. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: IFS? (Comment must be at least 15 characters in length!)

Comment: Iterated function system: A method to create fractals. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system)

Comment: @JonasGröger yea. I've only ever worked on one fractal before so I'm not great.